# In CMake, how can I find the directory of an included file?

Tags: file, cmake

Suppose my project's `CMakeLists.txt` includes `foo.cmake`:

```
include(foo)
```

In `foo.cmake`, i want to know the path of `foo.cmake`. 

How can I do that?

Note that `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` gives the directory of the including `CMakeLists.txt`, not that of the included `foo.cmake`, and is thus not what I want.

Of course, `foo.cmake` might be included by several projects (i.e., by several `CMakeLists.txt` files).

Comment: What version of CMake are you using?  In 2.8.9 on Windows 7, [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR) behaves as per the documentation. i.e. if `foo.cmake` contains the command `message("foo dir - ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")` it outputs the directory containing `foo.cmake`, not that of the parent `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: Yes, `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` behaves as per the documentation. And no, this is not what I was looking for: I would have liked to get the directory of `foo.cmake`, not the directory of the `CMakeLists.txt` that includes `foo.cmake`.

Comment: You seem to be contradicting yourself here.  If you refer to `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` in CMakeLists.txt, it yields the directory of CMakeLists.txt.  If you refer to `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` in foo.cmake, it yields the directory of foo.cmake.

Comment: `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` in `foo.cmake` yields the directory of `CMakeLists.txt`, **not**, as you write, the directory of `foo.cmake` (except of course if those two directories happen to be identical). According to the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE): _Full path to the listfile currently being processed._, and my experiments confirm that this is indeed how `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` behaves.

Comment: [Robert Dailey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12827082/424459) is correct.  There's something far wrong if this is not what you're seeing.  Have you tried his solution?  If you have, and your results aren't as per his answer, can you post minimal example CMake files, your directory structure, your version of CMake, your platform details, and the commands you're using to invoke CMake?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

People have reported seemingly contradictory facts about how CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR behaves. Now I know the reason for the confusion:

First, in my Linux environment:

```
$ cd /path/to/home  
$ mkdir cmake-test  
$ cd cmake-test  
$ mkdir source  
$ mkdir source/subdirectory  
$ mkdir build
```

I create these two files:

```
$ cat source/CMakeLists.txt  
include(subdirectory/foo.cmake)  

$ cat source/subdirectory/foo.cmake  
message("CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR is ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")
```

CMake works as reported by Fraser and Robert Dailey:

```
$ cd build  
$ cmake ../source  
CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR is /path/to/home/cmake-test/source/subdirectory  
[...]
```

However, I add a function to foo.cmake, which I call from CMakeLists.txt:

```
$ cat ../source/subdirectory/foo.cmake  
message("CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR is ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")  
function(bar)  
    message("CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR in bar() is ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")  
endfunction()  

$ cat ../source/CMakeLists.txt  
include(subdirectory/foo.cmake)  
bar()
```

Then:

```
$ cmake ../source  
CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR is /path/to/home/cmake-test/source/subdirectory  
CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR in bar() is /path/to/home/cmake-test/source  
[...]
```

So, the value of CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR in foo.cmake is not the same at the time foo.cmake is included and when bar() is called. This is according to the specification of CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.

Here is one possible solution for accessing the directory of foo.cmake from within bar():

```
$ cat ../source/subdirectory/foo.cmake  
set(DIR_OF_FOO_CMAKE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})  
function(bar)  
    message("DIR_OF_FOO_CMAKE in bar() is ${DIR_OF_FOO_CMAKE}")  
endfunction()
```

after which I get the behavior I was looking for:

```
$ cmake ../source  
DIR_OF_FOO_CMAKE in bar() is /path/to/home/cmake-test/source/subdirectory  
[...]
```

Comment: OK - That makes sense now.  `function` in CMake effectively inlines the calls made within the function, so in your original case the "listfile currently being processed" was CMakeLists.txt even though the definition of the function was in another listfile.

Comment: Your design is wrong, IMHO. `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` is working as designed. Instead, put your bar function in the root CMakeLists.txt file and only call common functions in an upward path. In other words, do not call functions defined by lower-level CMake scripts from higher-level ones and you won't run into this problem.

Comment: "_put your bar function in the root CMakeLists.txt file_" Hmm... As I wrote in my very first post: "_Of course, foo.cmake might be included by several projects_" Are you suggesting that bar() should be duplicated in as many (root) CMakeLists.txt as it happens to be needed?!

Comment: And if bar is in a CMakeLists.txt included with add_subdirectory, you'll have to add PARENT_SCOPE to the declaration of DIR_OF_FOO_CMAKE: `set(DIR_OF_FOO_CMAKE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})  PARENT_SCOPE`)

Comment: This worked for me, with one caveat: use a unique variable name for each source file in which you use this technique.  Variables are not necessarily exclusively file-scoped!  (Tested with cmake 3.6.2)

Answer (score 19):

In CMake 3.17, you [have a new variable](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/release/3.17.html?highlight=cmake_current_function_list_dir#variables) available, called `CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR`, which can be used inside a function. It is undefined outside of a function definition.

```
function(foo)
  configure_file(
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR}/some.template.in"
    some.output
  )
endfunction()
```

Prior to CMake 3.17, `CMAKE_CURRENT_FUNCTION_LIST_DIR` functionality has to be approximated with `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` by the following workaround, taken from CMake documentation:

```
set(_THIS_MODULE_BASE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")

function(foo)
  configure_file(
    "${_THIS_MODULE_BASE_DIR}/some.template.in"
    some.output
  )
endfunction()
```

Answer (score 12):

See [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR):

> Full directory of the listfile currently being processed.
>
> As CMake processes the listfiles in your project this variable will
>   always be set to the directory where the listfile which is currently
>   being processed (CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE) is located. The value has
>   dynamic scope. When CMake starts processing commands in a source file
>   it sets this variable to the directory where this file is located.
>   When CMake finishes processing commands from the file it restores the
>   previous value. Therefore the value of the variable inside a macro or
>   function is the directory of the file invoking the bottom-most entry
>   on the call stack, not the directory of the file containing the macro
>   or function definition.

### Example

I have the following structure:

```
C:\Work\cmake-test\CMakeLists.txt
C:\Work\cmake-test\subfolder\test.cmake
```

In my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include( subfolder/test.cmake )
```

In my `test.cmake`:

```
message( "Current dir: ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}" )
```

The result I get when I run CMake from `C:\Work\cmake-test` is:

> Current dir: C:/Work/cmake-test/subfolder

Comment: `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` does not help the least in this situation.

Comment: I added an example to my answer to make it more clear for you.

Comment: This only works if you access it in the .cmake directly, not if you access the variable in a function or macro.

Answer (score 2):

The `include()` command searches for modules in `${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}` first and then in CMake `Modules` dir.

So you can just check for file presence with `if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}/foo.cmake)` and `if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/foo.cmake)`.

Comment: From CMake documentation: "CMAKE_MODULE_PATH: List of directories to search for CMake modules." So, one would have to check for all the elements of CMAKE_MODULE_PATH, and then ${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules. Not impossible, but... isn't there anything more convenient?

Comment: The included .cmake file (`foo.cmake` in my example) refers to a directory. The location of that directory is well defined relatively to the .cmake file, so I would have liked to refer to it with something like `${PATH_OF_THIS_CMAKE_FILE}/<path relative to the .cmake file>`.

Comment: Take a look at `include` documentation, the exceptional case: http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command:include It seems that you can do `include(relative/path/to/file)` in your foo.cmake and it would work.

Comment: I tried the suggested `include(relative/path/to/file)`, but it does not work. I will resort to the solution that you originally proposed, or to some workaround.