# How to define a cmake macro in a sub_directory that uses the CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR?

Tags: cmake

What I want to do is to create a `CMakeLists.txt` that defines a convenience macro to use in parent scope. I can use the macro just fine. However, I used the `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}` which is unfortunately not the directory of the CMake script the macro is defined in, but the one it is called from. Is there any way I can change that?

MWE

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(git_info CXX)
macro(do_stuff)
    message("This CMakeLists.txt file is in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
endmacro()
```

One ugly way I found was to export variables to the parent scope that contain the path and use that in the macro. But I would prefer to only export the macro definition, if possible, to keep things clean.

**Edit:**
To clarify a bit. I have one folder with my top-level`CMakeLists.txt` and one folder (`my_folder`) inside with the above MWE `CMakeLists.txt`. The top-level `CMakeLists.txt` looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(top_project CXX)
add_subdirectory(my_folder)
do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to transfer [`CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html) outside the macro into another variable or - in your case - a user defined global property:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY DoStuffPath "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}")

macro(do_stuff)
    get_property(_my_marcros_file GLOBAL PROPERTY DoStuffPath)
    message("This CMakeLists.txt file is in ${_my_marcros_file}")
endmacro()
```

That also works when the macros are defined in a file added with [`include()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include.html).

**References**

- [In CMake, how can I find the directory of an included file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802377/in-cmake-how-can-i-find-the-directory-of-an-included-file)
- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)

Comment: This has the issue, that, since the macro is called in parent_scope, `_my_marcros_file` is invisible to the place where the macro is defined. Thus the printed message will be ("This CMakeLists.txt file is in ").

Comment: I added some clarification to the question.

Comment: But it is the other way around. I want to use the macro defined in the child scope in parent scope. Which works, but I don't want to make the variables of the child scope visible to the parent scope.

Comment: @MrZ Ok. I've just see your changed question. Modified my code to work in your scenario also by using a user defined global property.

Answer (score -1):

Use  [CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) to get a path to outermost parent CMakeLists.txt.