# How to enforce cmake performs "traget_link_libraries" after a library has been created

Tags: cmake

I want to write some executable code which depends on some third-party libraries and a self-define library(mylib), Is there any way to enforce the target_link_libraries performs after mylib has been created?

Comment: Why not just do `target_link_libraries` before `mylib` is created?

Comment: I used a variable ALL_LIBRARIES to store all libraries that I need, and use list(APPEND ALL_LIBRARIES mylib) to update it. Finally  linked the target with ${ALL_LIBRARIES} use target_link_libraries(target ${ALL_LIBRARIES})

Comment: I do not understand. Sure, so why not just do `target_link_libraries(... mylib)` from the start?

Comment: Inspired by you, I did some change: directly link the target with mylib by target_lint_libraries(target ${ALL_LIBRARIES} mylib), and it success, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target doesn't have to exist to link with it. Just `target_link_libraries(... mylib)` from the start, and define target `mylib` later.

When you forget about defining `mylib` target, you will get `-lmylib: could not find library` message from the linker, or messages about missing headers when compiling (depending if the target exports some include paths).

> Is there any way to enforce the target_link_libraries performs after mylib has been created?

Yes, you can overwrite `add_library` function with a custom handler that checks the name of the library and executes specific action on it. For example ['Overwrite' cmake command using a macro and restore its default behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44623238/overwrite-cmake-command-using-a-macro-and-restore-its-default-behavior) .