# Get file of current macro file in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, path, include

I'm writing a .cmake file that handles a bunch of stuff and needs access to an executable in a fixed relative path to the .cmake file. In this instance, the orgianization looks like this:

```
CMakeLists.txt 
   - cmake
       - tools.cmake 
       - bin
           - exectuable.exe
```

The issue is that `tools.cmake` is included using `include` and thus, `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` returns the directory of the `CMakeLists.txt`. The reason I don't want to hardcode the path is that I want to put the `tools.cmake` and binary in a separate GIT repository and I don't want to force the user to place it in some specific folder.

Only solution I can come up with right now is to supply a function that sets and stores the path to `tools.cmake`. That's not really elegant.

Comment: Are `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE` and `CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR` the variables you are looking for?

Comment: @vre as described, they are not returning the `tools.cmake` but the `CMakeLists.txt` in which `tools.cmake` is included.

Comment: I'm get it to work by having the user store the variable to the path manually using properties. But I'ld really like to skip that step.

Comment: Indeed, damn. But yes, I'll add an answer and mark as dup

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854575/2532768

`CMAKE_JUCE_TOOLS_PATH`does not return the correct path within functions or macros in `tools.cmake` but it results in the correct path outside any function. So one can us

```
set(PATH_TO_TOOLS_CMAKE ${CMAKE_JUCE_TOOLS_PATH})
```

to store the path while it can be accessed in a variable and than access `PATH_TO_TOOLS_CMAKE` in functions and macros